# Restoring sqlite.db file after downloading it from gmail

Tags: java, android, gmail, android-sqlite, database-backups

I need some help i am working on backup and restoring sqlite.db file , In this process i store a copy of db file in my device storage and restore it from there which is working perfectly fine. But when i send this file through any email server like gmail and download it into my storage it add timestamp to its name i handled that in code but it says file not found exception ,i guess gmail is not downloading  it properly in storage or not giving access to other apps .
Whenever i rename that file just replacing  any alphabet  from that name than i can restore that file please help me out i am stuck here ,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :
My problem was when a file is downloaded from gmail or any other server when we try to get its path it does not give its actual path it give path like /downloads/@2386
so when i try to open it, it shows file not found exception so to overcome this problem i have to get actual file path from that path, after  getting that path and try to open it, it works perfectly fine.